# Closing the xml tag in one line

Tags: python, xml

The loop goes through the list

```
                for file in files:
                    if id == file['param_id']:
                        resources_dict = {'fileNo': str(i), 'startPageNo': str(i), 'endPageNo': str(i),
                                          'format': 'cpk:JPEG'}

                        ET.SubElement(cpf_resources, 'cpf:ContentFile', resources_dict).text = 'cid:{}'.format(str(file['filename']))
                        i = i + 1
```

then the data is written to the file as follows:

```
 tree = ET.ElementTree(jobticket)
        filename = '{}\\{}.xml'.format(os.getcwd(), get_af_value(project_data, id, 'filename'))
        tree.write(filename, encoding="UTF-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

In the end file, the data are displayed as follows:

```
 <cpf:Resources>
        <cpf:ContentFile endPageNo="1" fileNo="1" format="cpk:JPEG" startPageNo="1">cid:page_0005.jpg
        </cpf:ContentFile>
        <cpf:ContentFile endPageNo="2" fileNo="2" format="cpk:JPEG" startPageNo="2">cid:page_0009.jpg
        </cpf:ContentFile>
    </cpf:Resources>
```

Is there a way to display the closing of the tag  `</cpf:ContentFile>`in the same line?

```
<cpf:ContentFile endPageNo="2" fileNo="2" format="cpk:JPEG" startPageNo="2">cid:page_0009.jpg</cpf:ContentFile>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use toprettyxml() to give xml tag and text in same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31754461/how-to-use-toprettyxml-to-give-xml-tag-and-text-in-same-line)

Comment: I saw that. Unfortunately, I use xml lib not, lxml.I'd have to rebuild the entire script to customize it under lxml.

Comment: The line on which an XML closing tag appears is insignificant (aside from mixed content, which isn't in play here).  If you're worried about aesthetics, use a customizable serializer, aka pretty printer.  If you're worried about breaking consuming applications, don't; they're broken if they have such a dependency and should be fixed, not catered to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few curses I managed to create something like this:

```
        tree = tree.getroot()
        tree = ET.tostring(tree)
        xmlstr = minidom.parseString(tree).toprettyxml(indent = "   ", encoding='UTF-8')
        with open("filename.xml", "w") as f:
           f.write(xmlstr)
```

Maybe somebody could use it.